# Skip ajax (or any other procedure) from another event (or function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-deferred

So problem is that there, we have a 2 tabs, 1st tabs loads a content by ajax1, and 2d tab loads a content by ajax2. So use case: Click 1st tab, loading ajax content. Did a fast click, do not wait while ajax finished. The tab2 content (ajax2 finished faster than ajax1) is shown, but ajax1 just finished and override a content block. In general we had a 2d tab selected but 1st tab content loaded.

The solution looks like below code I know and I want more fancy solution. Please:

```
var isLoading = false;
tabs.on({
    click: function () {
        if (isLoading) return;
        isLoading = true;
        tab.load(function () {
            isLoading = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How come the content block of the tabs are the same? Would it not make sense to have a content block for each tab, and just toggle visibility when switching tabs? This would both solve your problem and prevent loading on every tab-switch..

Answer (score 0):

Disable the click event of other tabs when one tab is clicked, then enable them afterwards?

Comment: Is that not the exact same result? Either way, the user is unable to click tabs while one is loading, leaving the user thinking it does not work.

Comment: @ThorJacobsen I agree about the user may think that the other tabs does not work till ajax1 is over and the content block should be seperate as you suggested, but what do you mean by "exact same result", if at onclick the other tabs are disabled, how can the user still invoke the other tabs' ajax? I don't get it!

Comment: I mean, that disabling the click-event (as you suggest) or just returning on-click (as OP suggests) behaves the same from the users point of view.

Comment: For now this issue fixed the same way, but I think this is not correct, we haven't any right to block user interface, right? I think this is bad practices.

Comment: @Dmitry Not Necessarily, There are UIs out there where the rest of the tabs are disabled (but visible) till the user finishes filling up and saving the first tab, online shopping, registrations so on... But definitely having different content blocks instead of toggling the content of the same one is a good practice like Mr. Thor suggested.